# What is a qualifer when making a new resource directory in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making the various drawable directories in an android studio project and it has the option of qualifiers.
It has a list of available qualifiers and another area for chosen qualifiers.

What is a qualifier? How does it effect the project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is a qualifier?

It is a constraint, indicating that the directory's worth of resources is targeting a particular certain devices and configurations.

So, for example:

- `res/layout/` is good for anything, but `res/layout-land/` is for landscape orientations
- `res/values/` is good for anything, but `res/values-fr/` is for French, and `res/values-v11/` is good for devices running API Level 11 or higher

You can read more about resource set qualifiers in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).